# List expects 3 elements but I don't know from where third comes

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0

So I was trying to follow a tutorial for oAuth 2.0 from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/99431/oauth-2-with-swift-tutorial).
Under the section "OAuthSwift with Embedded Web View".
This is the whole function:

```
// 1 Create OAuth2Swift object
let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
  consumerKey:    "YOUR_GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID",         // 2 Enter google app settings
  consumerSecret: "YOUR_GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET",
  authorizeUrl:   "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  accessTokenUrl: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  responseType:   "code"
)
// 3 Trigger OAuth2 dance
oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL(
  NSURL(string: "com.raywenderlich.Incognito:/oauth2Callback")!,
  scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",        // 4 Scope
  state: "",
  success: { credential, response in
    var parameters =  [String: AnyObject]()
    // 5 Get the embedded http layer and upload
    oauthswift.client.postImage(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files",
      parameters: parameters,
      image: self.snapshot(),
      success: { data, response in
        let jsonDict: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
          options: nil,
          error: nil)
        self.presentAlert("Success", message: "Successfully uploaded!")
      }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
        self.presentAlert("Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
    })
  }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
    self.presentAlert("Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
})
```

I get an error on point 4 (scope) where the list is filled:

```
  success: { credential, response in
    var parameters =  [String: AnyObject]()
```

It says it expects 3 arguments but specified are just two. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the two arguments were valid back when the tutorial was made (or last updated), and now it requires three arguments. So, replace:

```
success: { credential, response in
    var parameters =  [String: AnyObject]()
    ...
```

with:

```
success: { credential, response, parameters in
    ...
```

The `let jsonDict` line also follows an old format, and doesn't handle errors, so change it to:

```
do {
    let jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
    // And replace [String: AnyObject] with your JSON format.
} catch {
    // Error handling here
}
```

Comment: So, basically I have to remove the whole line `var parameters =  [String: AnyObject]()`? And add the `parameters` as the third expected argument? When I did this, I got an error on `let jsonDict: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)` which is:"Extra argument error in call".

Comment: Thank you, but now there is problem because of error handling. I've to do it with try and catch...